# typesetting 2 line conditions over which is summed

Tags: math-operators, subscripts

I am trying to typeset the formula below in a way that `m_j=m_i` and `z_j=z_i` have the same scriptsize, the `=` are aligned, and `j:` is before both, larger and with vertical position between the lines. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  y&=\sum_i\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sum_{j:_{m_j=m_i}^{z_j=z_i}}
    {f(m(j),z(j),s(j))}}\right)^2}{1}\\
  y&=\sum_i\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sum_{j:\substack{m_j=m_i\\z_j=z_i}}
    {f(m(j),z(j),s(j))}}\right)^2}{1}\\
  y&=\sum_i\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sum_{j:\stackrel{m_j=m_i}{z_j=z_i}}
    {f(m(j),z(j),s(j))}}\right)^2}{1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle for correcting the error in my post introduced by a corrupted database [https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also want to consider using the `subarray` environment provided by the `amsmath` package.

In the MWE below, the first equation uses this environment to typeset the "inner" formula of your example. The second equation, which places this inner formula into the full expression, looks cramped because, by TeX's rules, the contents of the inner formula are all set in scriptscriptstyle/scriptstyle. At the same time, the parentheses that surround the numerator are over-sized because they use `\left` and `\right` directives. Relative to the second equation, the third equation uses (i) the `\dfrac` command to restore the overall look of the inner formula, (ii) a pair of `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` parentheses to help distinguish visually among the plethora of parentheses, (iii) a pair of `\Biggl(` and `\Biggr)` directives to surround the numerator, and (iv) the `\mathlarger` command (which is provided by the `relsize` package) to increase the size of the outer summation sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,relsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\sum\nolimits_{j:\, 
         \begin{subarray}{c}
           m_j=m_i \\ z_j=z_i
         \end{subarray}}
    f(m(j),z(j),s(j)) \\
y = \sum_i \frac{\left( 1-\frac{1}{
    \sum\nolimits_{j:\, 
         \begin{subarray}{c}
            m_j=m_i \\ z_j=z_i
         \end{subarray}}
    f(m(j),z(j),s(j))}\right)^2}{i}\\
y = \mathlarger{\sum}_i \frac{\Biggl( 1-\dfrac{1}{
    \sum\nolimits_{j: \,
         \begin{subarray}{c}
            m_j=m_i \\ z_j=z_i
         \end{subarray}}
    f\bigl(m(j),z(j),s(j)\bigr)}\Biggr)^2}{i}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like in @egreg's response that the conditions are smaller than the j, but the larger sum sign is definitively a good idea.

Comment: To get the conditions typeset smaller than the letter `j`, just replace the line `m_j=m_i \\ z_j=z_i` with `\scriptscriptstyle m_j=m_i \\ \scriptscriptstyle z_j=z_i` (i.e., precede each condition with its own `\scriptscriptstyle` directive).

Answer (score 6):

This is possible also with standard LaTeX methods, but in this case a direct approach with TeX primitives is handier

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\mycomplicatedsubscript{
  j\colon
  \vcenter{
    \offinterlineskip
    \halign{
      \hfil$\scriptscriptstyle##$&$\scriptscriptstyle##$\hfil\cr
      \mathstrut m_j&=m_i\cr\noalign{\kern1pt}
      z_j&=z_i\cr
  }}
}

\begin{document}

\[
  y=\sum_i\frac{\biggl(1-\dfrac{1}{\sum_{\mycomplicatedsubscript}f(m(j),z(j),s(j))}\biggr)^2}{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\dfrac` and of `\biggl` and `\biggr` rather than `\left` and `\right` that would unbalance the parentheses, because the denominator is much taller than the numerator.
[image]

Comment: Why `m^{}_j` instead of just `m_j`?

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann It's a remain of a previous attempt. The `\mathstrut` in the first line is better for getting the `j:` in the middle, as it compensates for the subscript `j` at the bottom.

Comment: @MarkusSchmassmann Sorry, but I don't think that a larger summation symbol is a good idea.